# My FB app disappeared

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I'm a Developer and have had a game app on Faceook for over a years. Yesterday it disappeared. How do I find otu what happened and how to restore it?

Comment: You could try talking to facebook tech support. That'd be some OTHER site, not this one.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 3):

Usually when a Facebook app has been removed, it is due to a policy violation.
Make sure to check your email for any notices from Facebook.

If you do find your app has been disabled, you can try follow the steps from Facebook:
https://www.facebook.com/help/155308851202619/

Quote from the above link:

> 1. Make sure you’re logged in to Facebook from your developer account.
> 2. Go to the email Facebook sent you when your app was restricted and click the link to appeal. If you can’t find this email, you can visit the [Appeal Page](https://developers.facebook.com/appeal) on the Developer app.
> 3. Make sure you’re seeing information about the app that was restricted, and follow the instructions on the Appeal Page. Our team will review your appeal and may grant you access to your app if it was erroneously removed or restricted. Please understand that not all appeals are granted.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks. very useful. When you are in such condition, Facebook doesn't mention about the /appeal page at all.